# Modified Bland–Altman plot in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, machine-learning, seaborn

My lab uses what our PI calls "modified Bland–Altman plots" to analyze regression quality. The code I wrote using Seaborn only handles discrete data, and I'd like to generalize it.

A [Bland–Altman plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot) compares the difference between two measures to their average. The "modification" is that the x-axis is, instead of the average, the ground truth value. The y-axis is the difference between the predicted and true values. In effect, the modified B–A plot can be seen as **the plot of residuals from the line y=x**—i.e. the line `predicted=truth`.

---

The code to generate this plot, as well as an example, is given below.

```
def modified_bland_altman_plot(predicted, truth):
    predicted = np.asarray(predicted)
    truth = np.asarray(truth, dtype=np.int)  # np.int is a hack for stripplot
    diff = predicted - truth

    ax = sns.stripplot(truth, diff, jitter=True)
    ax.set(xlabel='truth', ylabel='difference from truth', title="Modified Bland-Altman Plot")

    # Plot a horizontal line at 0
    ax.axhline(0, ls=":", c=".2")

    return ax
```

[image: Modified Bland–Altman plot]

Admittedly, this example has terrible bias in its prediction, shown by the downward slope.

---

I'm curious about two things:

1. Is there a generally accepted name for these "modified Bland–Altman plots"?
2. How can one create these for non-discrete data? We use `stripplot`, which requires discrete data. I know that seaborn has the `residplot` function, but it doesn't take a custom function for the line from which residuals are measured, e.g. `predicted=true`. Instead, it measures from the best-fit line it computes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a standard scatter plot here:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)


def modified_bland_altman_plot(predicted, truth):
    predicted = np.asarray(predicted)
    truth = np.asarray(truth) 
    diff = predicted - truth

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(truth, diff, s=9, c=truth, cmap="rainbow")
    ax.set_xlabel('truth')
    ax.set_ylabel('difference from truth')
    ax.set_title("Modified Bland-Altman Plot")

    # Plot a horizontal line at 0
    ax.axhline(0, ls=":", c=".2")

    return ax

x = np.random.rayleigh(scale=10, size=201)
y = np.random.normal(size=len(x))+10-x/10.

modified_bland_altman_plot(y, x)

plt.show()
```

Comment: what does the coloring indicate in this context?